# How can I set objects in the same line (alignment)?

Tags: html, css

I have bubbles and icons who spoke it.
As you see this icon appears at next new line.
How can I set them together in the same line?
Person A is a man with glasses, and Person B is tweet bird.

How can I fix my css?

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/4Tyey/

[image: pic]

**HTML**

```
<span id="chat">
  <span id="comment_645">
        <div class="me_icon">
          <p class="responsive-img">  
        <a href="/user/1"><img alt="X50" class="img-polaroid" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTHwJFqUSlCJvXdCKEQ9dPxPhx_FYOcbQqD_Hco7vTSwEK_eVpnD-qTWcBCmg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px" /></a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bubble me">
    18:03:02：<a href="/user/1">Person A</a><br />
    hi
        </div>
    </span>
  <span id="comment_644">
        <div class="me_icon">
            <p class="responsive-img">  
        <a href="/user/1"><img alt="X50" class="img-polaroid" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTHwJFqUSlCJvXdCKEQ9dPxPhx_FYOcbQqD_Hco7vTSwEK_eVpnD-qTWcBCmg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px" /></a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bubble me">
            17:54:43：<a href="/user/1">Person A</a><br />
    hey
        </div>
    </span>
    <span id="comment_643">
        <div class="me_icon">
            <p class="responsive-img">  
                <a href="/user/1"><img alt="X50" class="img-polaroid" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTHwJFqUSlCJvXdCKEQ9dPxPhx_FYOcbQqD_Hco7vTSwEK_eVpnD-qTWcBCmg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px" /></a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bubble me">
            17:54:00：<a href="/user/1">Person A</a><br />
            woohoo
        </div>
    </span>
  <span id="comment_642">
        <div class="me_icon">
            <p class="responsive-img">  
                <a href="/user/1"><img alt="X50" class="img-polaroid" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTHwJFqUSlCJvXdCKEQ9dPxPhx_FYOcbQqD_Hco7vTSwEK_eVpnD-qTWcBCmg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px" /></a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bubble me">
            21:15:25：<a href="/user/1">Person A</a><br />
            ok
        </div>
    </span>
    <span id="comment_641">
        <div class="me_icon">
            <p class="responsive-img">  
                <a href="/user/1"><img alt="X50" class="img-polaroid" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTHwJFqUSlCJvXdCKEQ9dPxPhx_FYOcbQqD_Hco7vTSwEK_eVpnD-qTWcBCmg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px" /></a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bubble me">
            20:47:34：<a href="/user/1">Person A</a><br />
            Howdy
      </div>
    </span>
    <span id="comment_638">
        <div class="bubble you">
            20:36:49：<a href="/user/2">Person B</a><br />
            hello
        </div>
        <div class="you_icon">
            <p class="responsive-img">
                <a href="/user/2"><img alt="2011-08-16_20.01.51" class="img-polaroid" src="http://www.miraiha.net/wpblog/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/designreviver-free-twitter-social-icon.jpg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px" /></a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </span>
    <span id="comment_634">
        <div class="me_icon">
            <p class="responsive-img">  
                <a href="/user/1"><img alt="X50" class="img-polaroid" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTHwJFqUSlCJvXdCKEQ9dPxPhx_FYOcbQqD_Hco7vTSwEK_eVpnD-qTWcBCmg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px" /></a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bubble me">
            13:48:48：<a href="/user/1">Person A</a><br />
            How's this?
        </div>
    </span>
    <span id="comment_633">
        <div class="me_icon">
            <p class="responsive-img">  
                <a href="/user/1"><img alt="X50" class="img-polaroid" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTHwJFqUSlCJvXdCKEQ9dPxPhx_FYOcbQqD_Hco7vTSwEK_eVpnD-qTWcBCmg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px" /></a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bubble me">
          13:48:29：<a href="/user/1">Person A</a><br />
          test
        </div>
    </span>
    <span id="comment_631">
        <div class="me_icon">
            <p class="responsive-img">  
                <a href="/user/1"><img alt="X50" class="img-polaroid" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTHwJFqUSlCJvXdCKEQ9dPxPhx_FYOcbQqD_Hco7vTSwEK_eVpnD-qTWcBCmg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px" /></a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bubble me">
            13:25:55：<a href="/user/1">Person A</a><br />
            hello
        </div>
    </span>
    <span id="comment_630">
        <div class="me_icon">
            <p class="responsive-img">  
                <a href="/user/1"><img alt="X50" class="img-polaroid" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTHwJFqUSlCJvXdCKEQ9dPxPhx_FYOcbQqD_Hco7vTSwEK_eVpnD-qTWcBCmg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px" /></a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bubble me">
            13:00:33：<a href="/user/1">Person A</a><br />
            Nice to know you
        </div>
    </span>
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.chat {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;

}

.bubble{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    word-break: break-all;
}

.bubble::before {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    content: "\00a0";
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    transform:             rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -moz-transform:    rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -ms-transform:     rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -o-transform:      rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -webkit-transform: rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    width:  20px;

}

.me {
    float: center;   
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
    width: 85%;
    text-align: left;   
}

.me_icon {
    float: left;   
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
    width: 85%;
    text-align: left;    
}

.me::before {
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
    left: -9px;           
}

.you {
    float: center;    
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
    width: 85%;
    text-align: left;          
}

.you_icon {
    float: right;    
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
    width: 85%;
    text-align: right;          
}

.you::before {
    box-shadow: 2px -2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
    right: -9px;   
}
```

**OUTPUT that I want**

```
       ____________________
IconA < 20:47:34: Person A |
       | Howdy             |
       |___________________|
        ____________________ 
       | 20:36:49: Person B |
       | hello ?             > IconB
       |____________________|
```

**Not like this**

```
       ____________________
IconA < 20:47:34: Person A |
       | Howdy             |
       |___________________|
 ____________________ 
| 20:36:49: Person B |
| hello ?             > IconB
|____________________|
```

Comment: @j08691 What do you mean?

Comment: I mean no such thing exists. What is your doctype set to?

Comment: Can you change the HTML or only the CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For achieving this completely, you need to change your html structure also.
It is not a good idea to use percentage sizes.

See the **[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/5r6UM/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="chat">
 <div id="comment_641">
            <div class="me_icon">
                <p class="responsive-img">  
        <a href="/user/1"><img alt="X50" class="img-polaroid" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTHwJFqUSlCJvXdCKEQ9dPxPhx_FYOcbQqD_Hco7vTSwEK_eVpnD-qTWcBCmg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px" /></a>
</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bubble me">
            20:47:34：<a href="/user/1">Person A</a><br />
            Howdy
            </div>
    </div>
 <div id="comment_638">
   <div class="you_icon">
                <p class="responsive-img">  
        <a href="/user/2"><img alt="2011-08-16_20.01.51" class="img-polaroid" src="http://www.miraiha.net/wpblog/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/designreviver-free-twitter-social-icon.jpg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px" /></a>
</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bubble you">
               20:36:49：<a href="/user/2">Person B</a><br />
            hello
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

.chat {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        display:inline-block;

```
}    
.bubble{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    word-break: break-all;
  margin-left:89px;
  margin-right:89px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}    
.bubble::before {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    content: "\00a0";
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    transform:             rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -moz-transform:    rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -ms-transform:     rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -o-transform:      rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -webkit-transform: rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    width:  20px;

}
.me {
    float: center;   
    text-align: left;   
}    
.me_icon {
    float: left;   
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}    
.me::before {
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
    left: -9px;           
}    
.you {
    float: center;    
    text-align: left;          
}
.you_icon {
    float: right;    
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
    text-align: right;          
}   
.you::before {
    box-shadow: 2px -2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
    right: -9px;   
}
```

Comment: @Wold Thanks for answer. Could you please see the bottom of my Question. Can you make it?

Comment: that makes it more simple. Updated my answer and demo

Comment: If possible, could you please modify my CSS please???? I don't get it what to fix on my code:(  Here's my demo http://jsfiddle.net/4Tyey/

Comment: Updated.. Happy coding.. )

Comment: Thanks but one thing! If the same person is talking twice in a row, it messes up:(

Comment: I found out why!! please check this http://jsfiddle.net/5r6UM/3/  Bootstrap was preventing. Can you solve this?

Comment: Try replacing <span id="comment_652"> with div

Comment: Thanks, But it didn't help

Comment: If using <div id="comment_652">, add a style="overflow: hidden;" to it. In case of <span id="comment_652">, add a style="display: block;overflow: hidden;" to it.

Comment: what do you mean?? add style to HTML itself?

Comment: Change spans to <div id="chat"><div id="comment_652"><div class="bubble_row">. then add this style to css #chat>div { overflow:hidden; }

Comment: You missed the CSS class. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5r6UM/6/). Also `you_icon` div should come above `bubble you` div.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but your widths are too big on the me and you icons so I have made them smaller changing their widths to `40%` instead of `85%` and then added a `clear:both` on your bubble class:

http://jsfiddle.net/4Tyey/1/

Comment: I took a look at your example. But icon and bubble are not on the same line:(

Comment: the width on line 39 is still at 85%. Lowring it solves the problem. You mighty want to set thet to the width of the icon + margin in pixels. That way it is fixed.

Comment: Are right I thought you wanted the icons of you and me on the same line! I will edit my answer

Comment: @Pete Thanks for new example. It's almost there!!! If you narrow it down, icon appears at new line. Could you prevent that?

Comment: Is your site going to have a minimum width?

Comment: @Pete No but probably it could be something like 320

Comment: @Pete I just updated my question. Please check the bottom. Icon's width should be 50px by 50px

Comment: @Pete Thanks! This is perfect! What did you changed from the very first code?????

Comment: @Pete, and one more thing. If possible could you make the width of bubble as wide as possible???? Now I see big space between icon and bubble.

Answer (score 1):

Your icon widths are too wide and `float:center` does not exist.

I believe this is what you're looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/4Tyey/2/

Comment: Thanks. Almost there. Please narrow it down. Icon comes at the new line. Could you prevent that?

Comment: That's because you're using percentage based widths. Are these wrapped in another container with a set width, or do you want it to scale?

Comment: Yes, I don't care about that